# Symfony2 custom form field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I am very new to Symfony, so question might seem a little simple, but I need a help.

I have generated new bundle.

I have added a new route in `Me\MyBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml`:

```
my_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: MeMyBundle:Default:index }
```

Bundle controller looks in simple like this:

```
namespace Me\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->getForm()
        ;
        return $this->render('MeMyBundle::index.html.twig', array(
            'form'        => $form->createView(),
            'param1'      => 'some_string_1',
            'param2'      => 'another string',
        ));
   }
}
```

In the twig template I can read and process proper `params`, as I want.

Whole action happens in the generated form, where there are AJAX requests routed to another controller.

What I want to achieve is create a new custom form field, which could be reued in same form multiple times, with different `params`.

For example, I would like my `indexAction()` would have looked like this:

```
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $paramsArr_1 = array(
            'param1'      => 'some_string_1',
            'param2'      => 'another string',
        );
        $paramsArr_2 = array(
            'param1'      => 'some_string_2',
            'param2'      => 'another fine string',
        );
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add(myCustomField, $paramsArr_1)
            ->add(myCustomField_2, $paramsArr_2)
            ->getForm()
        ;
        return $this->render('MeMyBundle::index.html.twig', array(
            'form'        => $form->createView()
        ));
   }
```

Yes, I did see [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html), but it did not help me much. I could not get it working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `I could not get it working.` We can't help you without more information about your problem.

Comment: This article might help as well: http://www.webtipblog.com/create-a-custom-form-field-type-in-symfony-2/

Comment: @n.1 I have tried to follow step by step that article, but it is written quite briefly, and my solution caused lots of errors, which I coulnd't repair. Now I have undone all the changes. I do not want anyone to write it for me. I thought that, there is maybe some better tutorial or another example with custom form fields, which I can see and compare, or follow.

Comment: Thanks @joe42 it looks nice. I will try to follow this article.

Comment: Let me understand ... you need to add the new form ( returned from Ajax Call ) on a existing form ? .. in any way , you will need javascript/jquery to add this new form to your view after render it ... jquery functions like append and html aer very useful for that

Comment: You must create a custom form field type. In custom field type, you can control render process and submit process. If you want use ajax requester, then you modify `buildView` (Render process), and create widget for own field type and in widget you can write any JS scripts, html tags, etc...

Answer (score 0):

From what I know form fields extends the base form class, so your 'myCustomField' can be another form actually.

Check this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html

As you know each Form object has attached an object to it, so instead of your arrays you could create a new object with those values set on it, and then add that form how many times your want with objects containing different data.