# Using Symfony2 custom form field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

In refference to [my question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436932/symfony2-custom-form-field) a few hours ago, I will try to ask more specific question now.

I have followed guidelines from [official cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html), and [this article](http://www.webtipblog.com/create-a-custom-form-field-type-in-symfony-2/).

I have added new `class MyType extends AbstractType` in `Me\MyBundle\Controller\Form\Type` direcory.

I have created a template for that custom field type.

I have added proper entry in `config.yml` in order to use new template in forms.

But how can I use that custom field?

Let's say I have controller which looks like this:

```
namespace Me\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Me\MyBundle\Form\Type\MyType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('my_type', new MyType(), array('param' => 0))
            ->getForm()
        ;
        return $this->render('MyBundle::index.html.twig', array(
            'form'        => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Line `->add('my_type', new MyType(), array('param' => 0))` does not seem to have any affect on generating form. There is also no errors.

How can I make my custom field to be reused in the same form multiple times, with different `params`?

Edit:

`MyType` class looks like this:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'param' => 1,
            )
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_type';
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have some code for the MyType class?

Comment: @DerickF, yes I have. I have edited my question and added content of that class.

Comment: You should add it by typing `->add('whatever_name', 'my_type', array('param' => 0))`

Answer (score 0):

May try to implements buildForm method :

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options
{
    $builder->add(...);
}
```

Comment: Maybe try to use MyType::class or null instead of new MyType() !